# PROJ.4 How to create custom CRS to displace by x and y?

Tags: proj, epsg, coordinate-system

I'm trying to create a custom CRS with proj4. I need to displace coordinates by adding 10 meters east and 20 meters north from EPSG:32719.

How can I do that with PROJ.4?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The EPSG:32719 is a UTM Zone 19 south setup with:

```
$ grep  -B1 '<32719>' /usr/share/proj/epsg

# WGS 84 / UTM zone 19S
<32719> +proj=utm +zone=19 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs  <>
```

which is a shortcut defined in `/usr/share/proj/epsg`. For the background you can refer to the [PROJ.4 description](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OSGeo/proj.4/gh-pages/proj4.pdf). If you use the full parameter set for the *Transverse Mercator* projection, you could use **x_0** and **y_0** to shift the things a little bit more to your needs. With the full parameter set EPSG:32719 is defined as:

```
+proj=tmerc +ellps=WGS84 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-69 +k=0.9996 \
+x_0=500000 +y_0=10000000 +units=m +no_defs
```

and **x_0** and **y_0** are used to define false easting and ~ northing to prevent negative values in mapping. You could add your offset to +x_0=500010 / +y_0=10000020 ...

To test your setup you could use under LINUX:

```
$ echo -69 -40 | proj +proj=tmerc +ellps=WGS84 \
 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-69 +k=0.9996 \
 +x_0=500000 +y_0=10000000 +units=m +no_defs
```

which gives you:

```
500000.00   5572242.78
```

or

```
$ echo -69 -40 | proj +proj=utm +zone=19 +south\
 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```

the same values

```
500000.00   5572242.78
```

and

```
 $ echo -69 -40 | proj +proj=tmerc +ellps=WGS84 \
 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-69 +k=0.9996 \
 +x_0=500010 +y_0=10000020 +units=m +no_defs
```

for the shifted coordinates

```
500010.00   5572262.78
```

.
@ADD Where to get the infos...

Proj.4 uses a very condensed setup form (I like this), but you can get the infos from  [spatialreference.org](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/32719/prettywkt/) in the WKT form

```
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 19S",
      GEOGCS["WGS 84",
          DATUM["WGS_1984",
              SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                 AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
                 AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
              PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
           UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
           AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
           UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-69],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",10000000],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","32719"],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]
```

Translation of the parameter to the proj.4 terms in detail:

```
+ellps=WGS84 is the ellipsoid WGS84 which is also a shortcut
+k_0=0.9996  (alias scale_factor)typical areal correction
              factor for transverse mercator
+lat_0=0     (latitude_of_origin) allways 0 for UTM
+lon_0=-69   (central_meridian) 
+x_0=500000  (false_easting)
+y_0=1000000 (false_northing)
```

Environment Debian 8, BASH and PROJ.4

Comment: Wow. I never expected such an detailed answer!

Can you please explain how do you got the full parameter set?

Comment: @dfarfan Hm ..many things to read [equations and backgound](https://github.com/OSGeo/proj.4/blob/master/docs/old/USGS-Snyder-Map-Projections-A-Working-Manual-1987.pdf); [manual](https://github.com/OSGeo/proj.4/blob/master/docs/old/libproj.pdf) page 20 & 40 ff. & [UTM-Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system)